# Vista: Improving troubleshoot approach skills

Tags: windows-vista, troubleshooting

I'm not a Windows SuperUser, but neither *just* the regular user. I don't mind browsing the **Registry**, using **Process Explorer**, reading the **Event** logs, **(un)installing** new drivers and so on, but all this only makes me solve some problems.

I tend though to run into problems where these tools aren't enough. Which tools should I learn about to improve my troubleshooting skills in Windows?

Currently I'm using Windows Vista x64 (not moved to 7 yet), facing audio/video stuttering problems and I think this is a good place to improve my troubleshooting skills.

I know this post is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/64815/tips-for-approaching-a-hanging-computer) question, but my machine is only hanging occationally.

**Specs**:

```
Intel Q6600 Stock speed
ASUS P5QD Turbo
4GB ram
NVIDIA GTS-8800 640
HDA Xplosion 7.1
Seasonic 430W
Windows Vista Business x64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you should read [Mark Russinovich's blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/).

It gives a very deep insight into troubleshooting techniques using mostly Process Explorer.

Comment: @taspeotis: Thanks the link - I will bookmark that and read more into it :)

Comment: @taspeotis: As far as I can see, most of Marks articles are about subjects he can 'see'. In my case I can only hear the problem, thus I don't know what to look for. Can you or anyone else help me a bit further here?

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/04/07/3031251.aspx - use `xperf` and see where the computer is spending its time.