# Troubles with Procdump

Tags: command-line, dump

Recently I have been having issues with my computer hanging. Following the instructions from [the community FAQ](https://superuser.com/questions/224515/how-do-i-troubleshoot-hardware-issues-related-to-a-computer-freeze-crash%20to%20be%20specific), I installed Procdump so I could make a dump file to go over once my system hangs again.

So how do I use Procdump to perform a diagnosis? When I try to run it, the procdump command prompt shows up on screen for a split second then disappears so fast I can't even read it. I've tried running it from cmd and as an administrator, but cmd doesn't even find it and running it as an admin solves nothing.

Right now I have the Procdump folder at C:\Procdump, if that's any help.

Edit: I did get procdump working for me, but I have no idea where it is keeping the dump files that it makes.

Comment: Hey Landon, I would suggest asking for something specific here.  For example "How do I keep the procdump window displaying?" OR (this is really what you should ask): "How do I use procdump to diagnose a dump?"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see output of any console program - run it in the console. For example, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `cmd` and press enter.

Now you can use command prompt for executing and running console apps.

Comment: Now hopefully I can finally get to the bottom of my computer's problems